# Can Skydrive credentials be shared?

Tags: interop, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-phone, onedrive

I want to send info between a desktop/laptop/tablet app and Windows Phone. One possibility is to send data to the SkyDrive account and have the other end pick it up from there. Is this feasible? What I have in mind is the "Windows 8" app running on the desktop, laptop, or tablet allowing the Windows Phone app[s] to send data to its account. Is this possible, such as by providing the Windows Phone app with the Skydrive login info, or...???

Comment: As stated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/3204f035-e87e-4685-96a3-4f6812b7c864), using SkyDrive api to use it as application storage will breaks the term of use of the service.

Comment: This is not true. You can use SkyDrive as settings storage. I just spoke to the Program Manager of the SkyDrive team to verify this. The link you reference is no longer valid. I don't mean to contradict you, but not everyone knows the change that has occurred.

Comment: It's good to be contradicted in such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all the other questions you've posted around this query, it sounds like you want to put a mechanism in place to communicate between a Windows 8 app and a windows phone app.  I would recommend you look at building a service to handle the communication instead of trying to leverage mechanisms that weren't designed for what you want to achieve.

In direct answer to the this question, though, you can probably achieve it in this manner, but what happens if the user deletes the file you create?

Comment: Your deduction is correct. Basically, the "server" app (on Windows 8) needs to send a Y/N question to the Windows Phone[s]. If the answer is Yes, the Phone will continue to send short messages to the Windows 8 device on a regular basis. I don't worry about the user deleting anything, because the access would be behind the scenes, invisible to the user.

Comment: I'm thinking Raw Notifications (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Raw-notifications-sample-3bc28c5d) might be in my future

Comment: The only issue you will have there is receiving the notification if your app isn't running on the phone.  I still maintain you'd be better off with a service running somewhere to act as a broker.  I know Phone doesn't currently have an SDK for it by Azure Mobile Services may be something to look into - you can still access it with raw OData access from the phone.

Answer (score 1):

So, SkyDrive is unique to a user, not a device. This means if your application is running on more than one device you can use SkyDrive as a shared, unified storage option. Not just for files but also for application settings. There's an SDK for every platform, not just MS.

Here's what you need to consider.

The roaming API in Windows 8 puts information in a protected area of SkyDrive. As a result, the user cannot delete or screw up the files stored there. To that end, using SkyDrive as a shared location (like you are asking) doesn't have this benefit. The user can screw with your files or delete them - and wreck your app. There is no such thing as protecting your app files in SkyDrive (at this time).

Specifically, to your question:

The authorization model for SkyDrive requires a token that cannot be practically cached for any app. Also, you cannot cache credentials because you never get the credentials in the first place - you only get the resulting token. Listen, you would violate every possible best practice if you //asked// the user for their username and password and stored them. Please do not do this.

The final answer is this: an app on multiple devices can use SkyDrive as a shared storage solution for files and settings (like XML files) - but the developer needs to understand the risk and mitigate that (mitigation might be easy for your app). The user, on every device, would need to sign in and grant each application access to it folders. And, that's it.